# Using a variable string to define an intent to the next activity

Tags: android

I have a ListView with clickable components consisting of more than 25 items. What I want to achieve is when one of the items in the list is clicked it sends you to an activity related to that item.

For example:
In the list: Dog Species, Cat Species, Deer Species

When "Cat Species" is clicked: opens activity with information about different species of cats.

Now since i have a lot of items in the list, i do not want to create dozens of intents but want to use a string (that's received by clicking the specified item) to create an intent and start the activity related to that item.

So my question is: how can i convert a string into an intent?
In other words: how can i get the string "Cat Species" into a class item "CatSpecies.class"? which then can be used to start an intent to another activity.

Here the part of the code i'm using:

```
    @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {


            // ListView Clicked item value (including spaces): "Cat Species"
            String speciesValue = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

            // Name of the class, spaces removed: "CatSpecies"
            speciesValue = speciesValue.replace(" ", "");

            // Converts the speciesValue string into a .class: CatSpecies.class
            Class<?> speciesString = null;
            if (speciesValue != null) {
                try {
                    speciesString = Class.forName(speciesValue);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            // Starts the intent to the provided String: CatSpecies.class
            Intent speciesActivity = new Intent(this, speciesString);
            startActivity(speciesActivity);
        }

    });
```

Comment: did you get any error by executing the above code?

Comment: I get this error: Error:(83, 42) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(<anonymous OnItemClickListener>,Class<CAP#1>)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnItemClickListener> cannot be converted to String)
constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; <anonymous OnItemClickListener> cannot be converted to Context)
where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?

Comment: And at this part of the code [  Intent(this, speciesString);  ] it says: Cannot resolve constructor

Comment: You are passing "this" in intent. Above stated onItemclick represents anyonymouos inner class. try to pass Your activityname.this e.g. MyActivity.this

Comment: The above mentioned errors are gone now, but now the app crashes when i click an item on the list. Thank you for a step in the right direction!

Comment: :) please log your next error and lets see

Comment: It gives this error when an item is clicked: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Class.getName()' on a null object reference

Comment: Your approach makes no sense. If you have different Activities for each of your categories (Dog, Cat, Deer), why the need for intent? You already know the specie type that was selected from your listview. From there just launch your respective Activity.

Comment: Now, if you have ONE Activity, that covers all of your species and you do not want to use intents to pass data from your adapter to that Activity maybe you should consider a model class then.

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize a `Map<String, Class>` and just use that to get what you want, for example

```
 Map<String, Class> map;

 private void init() {

    map = new HashMap<String, Class>;
    map.put(ITEM_CAT, CatSpecies.class);
    ....
}
```

Then call

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {


    // ListView Clicked item value (including spaces): "Cat Species"
    String speciesValue = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

    Class clazz = map.get(speciesValue);
    // Starts the intent to the provided String: CatSpecies.class
    Intent speciesActivity = new Intent(this, clazz);
    startActivity(speciesActivity);
    }

});
```

That is one fast solution but idk if that would be *scalable*.

Anyways, for your code to work, you should also pass the **package** you are dealing with.

So, for instance, if the `CatSpecies` is in the same package as this class, you should have something like

```
Class<?> speciesString = null;
            if (speciesValue != null) {
                try {
                    speciesString = Class.forName(this.getPackage() + speciesValue);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

However that is very prone to errors as well.

In my opinion, the best solution would be for you to make your adapter extend `BaseAdapter`, and override the `getItem`. Inside the adapter, you would have access to all your classes, so

```
Class[] classes = new Class[] { CatSpecies.class, DogSpecies.class}

public Object getItem(int arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return classes[arg0];
}
```

So, that way, you could have something like

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {

    String speciesValue = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
    Class speciesClass = listView.getAdapter().getItem(position);

    Intent speciesActivity = new Intent(this, speciesClass );
    startActivity(speciesActivity);
    }
});
```